# preg_replace relative image path with expression

Tags: php, regex, path, preg-replace

i have a PHP variable $flexform with content from a MySQL Table Cell.

I want to remove all image paths from this variable with preg_replace. Possible Image pathes can be:

```
fileadmin/images/example/folder/dummy_001.jpg
fileadmin/images/example/dummy_002.png
/fileadmin/images/dummy_003.gif
```

like this:

```
$flexform = preg_replace('REGULAR EXPRESSION', '', $flexform);
```

How can i do this?

Comment: `$flexform = preg_replace('~\S+\.(png|jpe?g)$~', '', $flexform);`

Comment: You should post your attempt(s) if you don't want your post to be closed as off topic, since your question is like "do the work for me" and not "why my current code doesn't work?" .

Comment: Why use preg_replace()? Just use basename()

Comment: @BornKillaz: I think that paths are in a larger text.

Comment: @Avinash Raj: i have tried your code snippet, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte: Sorry, I'am a big nope in regex. My attempts were not worthy to show it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys. With the regex example from @Avinash Raj and the great regex sandbox linked from @ClasG, i got the solution for my problem:

```
$flexform = preg_replace('/([^\s]+)(\.*)\.(pdf|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)/i', '', $flexform);
```

Link to my Test-Sandbox: https://regex101.com/r/pJ9kR8/2

It was needed for a TYPO3 Extension called ke_search, which should index the contents from the templating extension flux/fluidcontent.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with

```
\/?(\w+\/)*
```

Check this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pJ9kR8/1)

Regards